# Meteor 1.0 - Passing a parameter into pathFor using iron:router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've seen a few answers on how to pass a parameter using iron:router as the third parameter, for example: `href="{{pathFor 'article' _id=this._id }}"`

What I would like to do is pass a parameter as the *second* variable (where `'article'` is in the example above).

I have a collection of `posts` that contain a `title`, a `body`, and a `type`. There are three types of articles in the project I'm working on, and each type needs to be routed to a different template because the formatting is significantly different.

What I would like to be able to do is route to a particular url based on the type. An example that captures my intent but doesn't work would be this:

```
<a href="{{pathFor '{{type}}'}}">link</a>
```

One of the "types" is "inquiry", and the route looks like this:

```
 @route "inquiryPost",
    path: "inquiry/:_id"
    data: ->
      Posts.findOne @params._id
    waitOn: ->
      [
        Meteor.subscribe "posts"
      ]
```

I've tried using a helper to pass the value into the `pathFor`, but that didn't work either:

```
path: ->
    type = @type
    "pathFor '#{type}'"
```

...with this on the front end:

```
<a href="{{path}}">link</a>
```

I can think of a few work arounds, but it seems to me like there should be an easier way to pass in parameters...

So, is it possible to pass in parameters into the second value of a pathFor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
   <template name="example">
    <a href="{{pathFor type}}">link</a>
   </template>
```

Where type is the helper

```
Template.example.examples({
 type:function(){
  return type;
 }
})
```

Also you can try with this for example

```
<a href="/myRoute/{{myHelper}}/{{this._id}}">link with many parameters</a>
```

Here you where accessing for example to the route

`/myRoute/type/rewr8671qew` for example

Comment: That solved it! Thank you. I ended up using `<a href="{{pathFor type}}">` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @samcorcos awesome =D!

Comment: could you please post up the complete working example for this - I'm trying to follow your answer but you don't show how to set the actual value of "type" !

Comment: hi andy type will be a simple string representing the name of your route and also i forgot to add that if you want to add parrams the route should look like this `{{pathFor 'someRouteName' id=this._id username=currentUser.username}}` wich will look like this on the browser `http://localhost:300/someRouteName/115q4rwqwwrd/myCoolUserName`

Comment: thanks for the response - I've tried again and it works this time, though I'm not entirely sure what I did differently from earlier!  I've not actually used a template helper as its the same 'header' template for every page, so instead I'm rendering the template from the router and passing in a data object to set the value.  If anyone reads this comment and wants an example of what I mean, quote my name and I'll get back to you