# passing arguments to iron:router pathFor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm building a menu in Meteor and missing something in the syntax.
I can only guess it's simple but couldn't find any strait question or answer about this, help appreciated.

So, I have one template to rule dem all:

```
<template name="navigator">
  <div class="navigator">
    {{>navButton type="home"}}
    {{>navButton type="find"}}
    {{>navButton type="account"}}
  </div>
</template>
```

my navButton template looks like this:

```
<template name="navButton">
  <div class="navButton">
    <p>
      {{#if type}}
        <a href="{{pathFor type}}"</a>
      {{/if}}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

the {{pathFor type}} doesn't work.
How can I simply use the type argument string **WITHOUT ANY JAVASCRIPT** (of course I'm naming the route and templates using the same name)

update:
i don't want to do this due to an implementation of a security pattern:

```
<a href="/{{type}}">{{type}}</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor 1.0 - Passing a parameter into pathFor using iron:router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461357/meteor-1-0-passing-a-parameter-into-pathfor-using-ironrouter)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the routes already set as my example, you can use

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'home'}}">Home</a>
```

Example of route mapping:

```
Router.route('/', {
      name: 'home'
    });
```

Comment: I want to pass 'home' as a parameter as shown in my code above.